# How to logout moodle in another site/external site

Tags: php, moodle

I have implemented logout moodle in my another php application when it logout then moodle automatically logout.

when using direct link www.moodle.com/login/logout.php at time confirmation it required how to disable this.

i have impliment single sign on/logout concept.

how to implement this concept.

Comment: if you post the code and which type of the confirmation you need to disable/enable?

Comment: echo $OUTPUT->confirm(get_string('logoutconfirm'), new moodle_url($PAGE->url, array('sesskey'=>sesskey())), $CFG->wwwroot.'/'); in logout.php

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the logout confirmation prompt you need to pass the user's session key to the logout script. I don't know how you'd achieve this from an external application though, so your only course of action may be to remove the 'else if' block starting at line 47 of https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/master/login/logout.php.

That would definitely achieve what you want, but obviously there may be negative implications to removing the session key check.

Hope this helps.

UPDATE:

Thinking about it some more, I guess you could just pass the Moodle session key to your external application during login as part of your SSO mechanism. Then you could pass it back later on for the logout.